# How to turn on and off gps in android using cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, gps

Im working on a phonegap/cordova project.Im trying to turn on or off in my app.I got code in native android app gps turn off and on.I dont know how to convert this in cordova/phonegap code.Is there any way to make gps on or off using cordova or phonegap.I used below link for native code:
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/calling-system-settings-android-app-gps-example

Answer (score 7):

i just made a plugin that do that.

[cordova-dialog-gps](https://github.com/rodrigo-martinezd/cordova-dialog-gps)

I hope you serve if so , remember to provide some feedback .

Comment: Consider answering the question along with providing the link to your library to make this answer even more useful.

Comment: Up-vote for you. Thanks, Same thing I was looking for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create plugin in native code for your cordova project, in that plugin place gps on off code. Pass the parameter from JavaScript to this plugin, based on the parameter value on or off the GPS

some links where you can learn creating plugins

http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/

http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/

http://www.plotprojects.com/developing-a-cordova-phonegap-plugin-for-android/